# Selecting the data inside a section tag

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get several sections of data in json in one go like

```
    <?php
      $host = "localhost";
      $user = "root";
      $pass = "";
      $databaseName = "world";
      $tableName = "city";
      $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
      $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName limit 15");  //query

      //fetch result   
    $jsonData = array();
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $jsonData[] = $array;
    }
   //first section
   echo '<section id="stuff">';
   echo json_encode($jsonData);
   echo '</section>';
   //section two ....
    ?>
```

I return json wrapped in html5 section tag

```
<section id="stuff">[["1","Kabul","AFG","Kabol","1780000"],["2","Qandahar","AFG","Qandahar","237500"],["3","Herat","AFG","Herat","186800"],["4","Mazar-e-Sharif","AFG","Balkh","127800"],["5","Amsterdam","NLD","Noord-Holland","731200"],["6","Rotterdam","NLD","Zuid-Holland","593321"],["7","Haag","NLD","Zuid-Holland","440900"],["8","Utrecht","NLD","Utrecht","234323"],["9","Eindhoven","NLD","Noord-Brabant","201843"],["10","Tilburg","NLD","Noord-Brabant","193238"],["11","Groningen","NLD","Groningen","172701"],["12","Breda","NLD","Noord-Brabant","160398"],["13","Apeldoorn","NLD","Gelderland","153491"],["14","Nijmegen","NLD","Gelderland","152463"],["15","Enschede","NLD","Overijssel","149544"]]</section>
```

This is my jquery

```
$.ajax({                                     
      url: 'getdata.php',                         
      data: "",     
      dataType: 'html',                
      success: function(data)         
      {
     //console.log(data);
     var thedata = $(data).filter($("#stuff"));
     console.log(thedata);
      } 
    });
```

This does not work.How can i select only the data inside the section tag?.

Comment: why u are targeting it in `<section>` when u dont want to have it ?

Comment: I want to return several data sets of related data in one json call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the inner of an element use .html()

```
$(data).filter('#stuff').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get back the json

```
$.ajax({                                     
      url: 'getdata.php',                         
      data: "",     
      dataType: 'html',                
      success: function(data)         
      {
       var thedata = $(data).filter('#stuff').html();
       var jobject = JSON.parse(thedata);
       for(var i = 0; i < jobject.length; i++) {
       var item = jobject[i];
       console.log(item[0] + ':' + item[1] + ':' + item[2] + ':' + item[3] + ':' + item[4] );
      }} 
    });
```